# Python, Bokeh Datetime Charting - blank output

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh, categorical-data

**The Problem**

I am trying to create a graph that shows a number of 'events' along a timeline. For instance, an injury was logged on 01-01-2018. I want to be able to log this sort of information for a range of different categories. However, my current attempt is just creating a blank chart -- So I assume that I've messed up royally somewhere and I would love some pointers.

**The Code**

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import output_file, show, save
import pandas
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource

# output file 
output_file=("justanotheroutput.html")

# constants
CATEGORIES = ['bed', 'injury', 'incident']

# get data source
df=pandas.read_csv("data.csv")
source = ColumnDataSource(df)

# create figure
f=figure(y_range=CATEGORIES, x_axis_type='datetime')

# create glyph
f.circle(x='date', y='category', source=source)

show(f)
```

**My Dummy Data**

[image: some random dummy data]

**My current Output**

[image: My current output]

Comment: Are those dates actual datetime values, or strings?

Comment: I guess that they would be strings -- I just created a CSV file using Excel to act as some dummy data. I wasn't aware that there was a specific distinction :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a datetime axis, Bokeh expects the coordinate values to be real datetime types. There are a variety of ways this could be accomplished, but the simplest is probably to tell Pandas which column is should treat as datetime. Here is a complete example based on a subset of your data (FYI images of data are far less useful in questions than including the real data somehow):

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

CATEGORIES = ['bed', 'injury', 'incident']

# use parse_dates to tell pandas which cols are datetimes
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", parse_dates=['date'])

f = figure(y_range=CATEGORIES, x_axis_type='datetime')
f.circle(x='date', y='category', size=20, source=df)

show(f)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you bigreddot. You're a genius lifesaver :) I can't wait to be learned enough to contribute back to stack overflow :)

Comment: I'm glad it's working, FYI I've updated the title to reflect that the question ended up being about datetimes

Comment: Good idea. In my ignorance I was just trying to be as descriptive as possible :D